# Soft: Advantages and big results using Homology in PDEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, homology-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology

I'm new to the viewpoint of using (co)homological methods in the theory of PDEs.  To help motivate me, I was wondering what are some significant results which have been obtained (primarily?) through the use of homological methods in PDEs?

Comment: I believe there is a particular result which is related to the Mountain Pass Theorem. I am not sure of the details however, this was discussed with my supervisor in passing.

Comment: ,What's the mountain pass theorem btw?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_pass_theorem